Why doesn't my iframe send back events to the parent window, even when it should?
Please use Firefox to browse the StackBlitz repo I provided. You won't see the result otherwise.
I have a list of elements, to which I attach a listener for "mousedown". I'm just trying to drag them around. You can see that the offsetX variable is calculated based on the window's computed style.
Now, if you scroll down a bit to where I'm rendering all of this, you can see I'm rendering them inside an iframe. If we hop into the iframe itself, we can see that all we're doing is attach listeners for the "mousedown", "mouseup", "mousemove" events that fire inside the iframe, specifically on the iframe.contentWindow. We then get the iframe's position, account for it, and when we create a new event with the code below:
const newEvent = new CustomEvent<{
  clientX: number;
  clientY: number;
  button: number;
  buttons: number;
}>(eventName, {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: false,
  detail: {
    ...e,
    clientX: e.clientX + frameRect.left,
    clientY: e.clientY + frameRect.top,
  },
});

it should all work. Then, we use window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(newEvent); to send back our event. Firefox's telling me that the event cannot be processed due to security reasons, but I tested even locally, and it's like the event just never fires from inside the iframe.
What am I doing wrong here? If you go back to where it gets rendered, and change to the items without the Iframe, it works as it should.
This is a simple window -> listen to events and iframe -> send events to the parent situation.
I've tried changing the iframe target to the contentWindow, to the document, and so on, thinking i have misunderstood where and how my events should land, but to no avail.
